# Global Variable Python

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x, global-variables

```
A=[]

def main():
    global A
    A=[1,2,3,4,5]
    b()

def b():
    if(len(A)>0):
        A=[7,8,9]
    else:
        if(A[3]==4):
            A.remove(2)

main()
```

This code gives error in line A.remove(2) giving reason:"UnboundLocalError: local variable 'A' referenced before assignment"

but A list is global and for sure it has been initialized in main() function.Please explain why this is giving error?

As A has been initialized again in b function, will this cause error?

Comment: Working just fine for me, on Python 3.4.3 and Python 2.7.12.

Comment: Can't reproduce. Working fine for me, Python 3.5. Is this your real code? Because maybe there is something in your real code you *think* isn't causing a problem that actually is.

Comment: working on python 2.7, 3.5

Comment: this is not my real code, i think this will work, will update the question in few minutes

Comment: please check code again, it gives error.

Comment: The problem is that `A` is redefined and initialized in one branch, but not the other. Python sees that you redeclare it, but what if it does to else? Then it won't see the new local `A` thus throwing the error. Put `global A` as the first line in `b`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you are getting this is because when you performed this assignment in your function:

```
A = [7, 8, 9]
```

The interpreter will now see `A` as a locally bound variable. So, what will happen now, looking at this condition:

```
if(len(A)>0):
```

Will actually throw your first `UnboundLocalError` exception, because, due to the fact, as mentioned, you never declared `global A` in your `b` function *and* you also created a locally bound variable `A = [7, 8, 9]`, you are trying to use a local `A` before you ever declared it.

You actually face the same issue when you try to do this:

```
A.remove(2)
```

To solve this problem with respect to your code, simply declare the `global A` back in your `b()` function.

```
def b():
    global A
    if(len(A)>0):
        A=[7,8,9]
    else:
        if(A[3]==4):
            A.remove(2)
```

However, the better, ideal and recommended way to do this is to not use global and just pass the arguments to your function

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]


def main(list_of_things):
    # do whatever operations you want to do here
    b(list_of_things)

def b(list_of_things):
    # do things with list_of_things

main(A)
```

Comment: @AndrewLi added some clarity.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare a variable `global` in any function that assigns to it.

```
def b():
    global A
    if some_condition:
        A.append(6)
    else:
        A.remove(2)
```

Without declaring `A` `global` within the scope of `b()`, Python assumes that `A` belongs in the b() namespace. You can read it, but cannot edit it (any changes made will not persist to the *true* `A`.

You're allowed to set A to something inside the function `A = ...` will work, but **only** within the scope of the function.

If you try to mutate A inside of the function without defining A in your function's namespace, then Python will tell you that you are trying to mutate a variable outside of your purview with `UnboundLocalError`

By declaring `A` `global`, the interpreter knows that you mean to edit the global variable.

I'm assuming that you meant for your code to look something like this (Otherwise, it runs fine)

```
A=[]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    def main():
        global A
        A=[1,2,3,4,5]
        b()

    def b():
        global A
        if some_condition:
            A=[7,8,9]
        else:
            A.remove(2)
        print A

    main()
    print A

print A
```